# Struct constructor calls this()

Tags: c#, struct, constructor, initialization

I came across the following code snippet and was wondering what the purpose of writing a constructor this way was?

```
public struct DataPoint{
    public readonly long X;
    public readonly double Y;
    public DataPoint(long x, double y) : this() {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }
}
```

Doesn't `this()` just set `X` and `Y` to zero? Is this not a pointless action seeing as afterwards they are immediately set to `x` and `y`?

Comment: It seems pointless now, but you could add a new property to `DataPoint` and then set it in the default constructor.

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari Not for a `struct`: you can't write a default constructor for a `struct`, in C#.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public DataPoint(long x, double y) : this() {
```

This calls the *default constructor* for the `struct`, which is automatically provided by the compiler, and will initialize all fields to their default values.

In this case, your custom constructor is assigning all fields anyway, so there's no point. But let's say you only assigned `X`, and didn't call the default constructor:

```
public struct DataPoint{
    public readonly long X;
    public readonly double Y;
    public DataPoint(long x) {
        this.X = x;
    }
}
```

This would generate a compiler error, because `Y` is not assigned in your parameterized constructor, and because you've defined it, the default constructor is not publicly visible to consumers.

Adding `this()` to the *initialization list* ensures that all fields are initialized, even if you aren't the one to do so.

Comment: Just a note: your snippet would generate compiler error not warning.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya That's what I meant, thank you. Fixed.