# In C#, why would you call : this() constructor if no default was defined?

Tags: c#

What purpose does the `:this()` serve in this example from the [C# documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is)

```
public struct Dog
{
   public string Breed { get; set; }

   public Dog(string breedName) : this()
   {
      Breed = breedName;
   }
}
```

Comment: Possible dublicate [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069565/struct-constructor-calls-this)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Struct constructor calls this()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069565/struct-constructor-calls-this)

Comment: @Ardit so the reason is in case later someone adds another field then it gets set to 0.

Comment: Not a duplicate of that: this question has the constructor call a property setter, that other question doesn't. The property setter makes a big difference. Without `: this()`, in this question, the code won't compile.

Comment: @user5389726598465 The this() should be called when you have a field and you are not initializing it the constructor.The base constructor will give the field a default value.

Comment: Odd how everybody is using a different C# compiler than the one I use.  I like mine better, structs follow the language specification.   I suspect it got included in the docs because of a wonky add-in that I don't use or on the off-chance that the author wanted to make refactoring to a class easier.

Comment: @HansPassant I am using the weekly build of Visual Studio 2017 and RBT's answer matched the compiler on test code today. *However* following along the tutorial in the *updated* ASP docs, the steps are already different from what the compiler outputs after a few months. But by and large the documentation has been great on ms docs and better than anywhere else.

Comment: Hmm, the only thing accurate in that answer is that the compiler just doesn't care that you add this().  It never did.  That structs always have a "default constructor" and that you can't declare one yourself is quite crucial to the way the CLR works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially how C# compiler treats reference types and values types differently when a parameterized constructor is present.

For reference types if a paramterized constructor has been defined by the programmer then compiler will *not* emit a default parameterless constructor but in case of Value types it still does like in your case. struct is a value type.

Even if I remove the call to default constructor then also below code works perfectly as compiler is emitting the default parameterless constructor which is being used by `Program` class:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var breed = new Dog();
        }
    }


    public struct Dog
    {
        public string Breed { get; set; }

        public Dog(string breedName) //: this()
        {
            Breed = breedName;
        }
    }
}
```

So effectively when you do :

```
public Dog(string breedName) : this()
{
    Breed = breedName;
}
```

You are actually calling that default constructor( which is not visible to us) before your parameterrized constructor kicks-in.

On same lines reference type don't work the same way:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var objMyClass = MyClass(); //gives error as compiler isn't emitting any default constructor
        }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass(int i)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without `: this()`, the code wouldn't compile with the C# compiler supplied with .NET Framework, because you might observe a struct field before it was initialised:

[image: Compiler error message]

Remember, you're calling a property setter, which can do anything other instance methods can do too.

```
public struct Foo
{
   public int bar;
   public int Baz {
     get { return 0; }
     set { Console.WriteLine(bar); }
   }

   public Foo(int value)
   {
      Baz = 0;
   }
}
```

This has to be invalid, because it would access the uninitialised `bar`. In order to make this invalid, the C# compiler doesn't allow struct constructors to call any instance methods, including property setters, until all fields have been assigned a value. Chaining `: this()` is an easy way to ensure all fields are initialised.

This rule was relaxed slightly in C# 6 in the Roslyn compiler.

Comment: `Without : this(), the code won't compile` - This is true only if you have at least one value type member in your struct. In OP's code snippet the only member is  `Breed` is a string (which is a reference type) so he should be fine even if he skips the call to parameterless default constructor from his parameterized constructor. Kindly correct me if I'm wrong in my thinking.

Comment: @RBT I had just edited after finding out there's a difference between the old C# compiler that still comes with the .NET Framework and the new Roslyn C# compiler. I messed up my testing, so I initially thought that was all, then I thought you were right there's another difference, now I went back to thinking that's all... :)